# SSH Connection Being Refused When I'm Remote, but not Local (Port Forwarding Already Enabled)

Tags: ssh

I set up SSH on my Ubuntu server (running XMonad) and generated a key for my laptop that I used to connect to my home server with.  I also went on my wireless router and forward port 22 for SSH use.  I can SSH fine when I'm at home using the standard:

```
ssh user@ipaddress
```

However when I'm outside of my local network I get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

Everything I read says I need to either a) check that my port 22 is forward (which it is) or b) check that sshd is actually running on my Ubuntu server (which it is).

Any ideas what is preventing my SSH from working when I'm remote?

Comment: When you say it works fine locally do you mean you can connect from another machine on your LAN or do you mean from the same Ubuntu box?

Comment: Do you only have a single modem/router, or are there two router devices together? Is your Ubuntu firewall allowing all traffic on port 22, not restricting to LAN? I guess there is also the unlikely chance your ISP could be firewalling port 22?

Comment: Yes, when I say I can connect fine locally, I mean I can connect from another machine (my laptop) onto my Ubuntu server via SSH.  There is only one router that is connected by ethernet to my server; however, I am SSH'ing from my laptop via a wireless connection.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line your ssh user config file if it doesn't exits You can create the config file as shown below.

`vi  ~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 300
```

Change the permission as below:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Restart the daemon. Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me sadly.  That isn't the location of my config file anyways, but I went to my ssh_config and changed the ServerAliveInterval - didn't help, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/a/371563/617303

For me this was the cause.

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `/etc/ssh_ssh_config` check to make sure GSSAPI Auth is disabled (set to `no`).

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Then restart the service or machine.